# rsync not working - want to copy only certain subdirectories and files

Tags: bash, rsync, copy

Hi let's say I have a directory like this:

```
/
    my_work
               /dir1
                    keepdir1.ddd
                    keepdir2.ddd
                    file.cfg
                    (lots of files and directories I don't want)
               /dir2
                    (same layout as dir 1)
```

So I want to copy the directory "my_work" and all of the "dir1", "dir2", etc sub directories.  But within each of those I want to keep only certain files, and certain directories. In the directories I keep I want to recursively include everything.

Here's what I've tried so far but nothing seems to copy:

```
rsync -rl --include-from=~/rsync_include /my_work ~/backup
```

And the contents of rsync_include are:

```
+ *file.cfg
+ *keepdir*/*
- *
```

**Update:**

If I run with rsync -rvvl I get:

```
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding directory my_work because of pattern *
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 10 bytes  received 12 bytes  44.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Comment: What's the output if you run it with `rsync -rvvl`?

Comment: I updated the question with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final `- *` is ignoring everything that hasn't explicitly matched one of the preceding rules.  This is what you want, but because the top level folders don't match,  rsync won't even descend *into* them, so it won't have a chance to match the file patterns you've specified.

If you add:

```
+ my_work/
+ my_work/dir*
```

explicitly to the top of the file, then it should work.